# Fire event after client side script validation in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, dom-events

Is there a way that I can execute a Javascript function after the client side validation occurs in asp.net?

I have a couple validation controls on a page and an input button with `CausesValidation=true`. The `OnClientClick` handler executes Javascript before the validation runs, but i want to run some functions afterwards.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET calls the **WebForm_OnSubmit**, thats runs the validation. After validation is ok, its continue and run the rest JavaScript functions that's found on **onsubmit** on the form.

So to execute a JavaScript after the side validation, just place it on the form tag.

For example:

```
<script>
  function CallMeAfterValidation()
  { 
    // here is the place to run your code
    return true;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return CallMeAfterValidation();" runat="server" ...></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an enhancement to the above solution (I too used it)

> If there are multiple buttons in your form and you want to run the
>   script only after the user clicks on one button, use the
>   **document.activeElement.id** It retrieves the current focussed element's ID.
>
> Using this you can run your script upon clicking a certain button.